# How can I understand this code (string as a function parameter in c)

Tags: string, pointers, char

I have written this code but its not working but when I replace ***targ and *sour by targ[] and sour[]** then its working. Also it shows many error when I call the function converge like this `converge(*targ, *sour)`. Please someone help me to understand this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void converge(char *target, char *src);
int main()
{
    char  *targ = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    char  *sour =   "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
    converge(targ, sour);
    //printf("%s", targ);
}

void converge(char *target, char *src)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0,j=strlen(src); i<=j; i++, j--)
    {
        target[i]= src[i];
        target[j]= src[j];
        printf("%s\n",target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a string like this:

```
char *targ = "abcd";
```

it is treated as read-only value, since the string `"abcd"` is stored in read-only memory, while the pointer `targ` is stored on your stack. Depending on your compiler you might get some warning unless you make this more explicit with `const char *targ = "abcd";`. An assignment like `targ[i] = src[i];` is not allowed in this case.

If you define a string like this:

```
char targ[] = "abcd";
```

a char-array will be created on your data stack, this string can be changed, since data on your stack is readable and writable. Additionally you can access the first element of your array as pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: please help me to understand this.
When i compile this code (save as a test.c)

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
 char  *targ = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        printf("%s", *targ);
}

it shows this warning message  

[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

And when I run this code it show me this message
test.exe has stopped working

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: Why it shows the warning message??
Is it not a valid way to print string as
printf("%s", *str);
If it is not a valid way then why it is not valid??

Comment: The message `[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char'` tells you that you're trying to convert a string to a single character, since your variable `char targ` is declared as `char` (single character) not `char *` (string or pointer to character).